# Testing website on Samsung default browser

Tags: testing, mobile, mobile-website, samsung-mobile

I have an issue with my site that only occurs on the default browser for the Samsung mobiles.(i.e S3)  Problem is, I don't have access to any of these phones to test with.
I tried the Samsung RTL emulator but this doesn't appear to allow you to browse websites, as there is no internet data connectivity.

Is there any other alternatives i use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the browser emulators available at http://www.browserstack.com/mobile-browser-emulator